# Integral on unit disk of a function with two singularities

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, complex, singularity

The goal is to prove, using Mathematica, that for $\mathbb{D}$ the unit disk and $u,v \in \mathbb{D}$, $u \neq v$,
$$\frac{1}{\pi} \int_{\mathbb{D}} \frac{\mathrm{d}^2z}{(z-u)\overline{(z-v)}} = \ln(1-u\bar{v}) - \ln|u-v|^2.$$

It looks like the techniques suggested in previous posts do not work. For example, the expression :

```
Integrate[
  (r/((u - r Cos[θ] - I r Sin[θ]) (v - r Cos[θ]+ I r Sin[θ]))), 
  {r, 0, 1}, {θ, 0, 2 π}, 
  Assumptions -> {0 < u < v < 1}]
```

or the same with more restrictive assumptions, returns `0`. This is contradictory with what `NIntegrate` returns when given specific values for $u,v$. (The values returned by `NIntegrate` do match the above formula).

Comment: `{0 < u, u < 0.5, 0.5 < v, v < 1}` can be replaced by `{0<u<v<1}`.

Comment: Sure, this is what I wrote in the first place, but it returned the value $0$. Then I tried to write it differently, but nothing helped.

Comment: ...thereby showing you should leave the condition in its shorter, more elegant form.

Comment: Done. Thank you. Do you know why it doesn't work ? Any suggestion on how to make it find the correct answer ?

Comment: I would write out everything in terms of reals and integrate `{x,-1,1},{y, -Sqrt[1-x^2],Sqrt[1-x^2]}` as a first try.

Comment: @DavidG.Stork This does not seem to work.  After a while,  `Integrate[
 Sqrt[x^2 + y^2]/((-u + x + I y)*(-v + x - I y)), {x, -1, 1}, {y, 0, 
  Sqrt[1 - x^2]}, Assumptions -> {0 < u < v < 1}]` gives errors of the form `Integrate: Integral of ` (complicated expression of u,v,x) `does not converge on {-1,1}.`